# Who is the author of Tantra sastras?

Tags: tantra

Who is the author of Tantra Sastras (if only one)?

If there are multiple authors, then what are the names of them?

Comment: your question is too broad, as there is not 'one' tantra (agama) shastra. there are similar questions to this already and probably one of them answers this. search on tantra and agama.

Comment: Yes, there have been similar questions @SwamiVishwananda..

Comment: Tantras are in the form of dialogues between Lord Shiva and the Goddess.. no authors are there

Comment: There is one, I'll look for a valid reference and post answer.

Answer (score 2):

Tantras are basically called 'Agama'-s (and often also 'Nigama'-s).

As per the website : https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/agama

> **The Aāgamas represent the wisdom that has come down from lord Śiva, received by Pārvatī and accepted by Viṣṇu so, it is termed as Āgama** [**1st** View]. Or, it represents the wisdom proceeded from the mouth of Śiva, received by Pārvatī, which is capable of removing three impurities are called as Āgamas. **The Śāktāgamas also holds the idea that of holy wisdom imparted by Devī to Īśvara** (**2nd** View). This is in consonance with Śaivāgamas.
>
> The Vaiṣṇavāgamas preache us the right behaviour, knowledge about the divine states and manner of obtaining them, and about the glory of God and reality (definitions found in this school treat āgama as a śāstra).
>
> (Source): Shodhganga: Iconographical representations of Śiva (h)

According to the Rudra-Yamala

> Agatam shiva-bakrebhyo gatam cha girijA-mukhe/matas cha vasudevasya tasmAd Agama uchchyate// **which supports the 1st view stated above.**

Nigama-s are also described as Tantra-s. According to Agamadvaitanirnayavachana

> nirgato girijaA-baktrAt gatash cha girisha-shrutam/matas cha vAsudevasya nigamah parikathyate// **This supports the 2nd view stated above.**

**Tantras are therefore 'God-Made' and do not have any human authors**.